# Increment arg in jq

Tags: json, increment, jq

I have something like:

```
jq --arg START 10 '[.z[] | select(has("name")) | {id: $START | tonumber, name}]'
```

transforming to an array of objects with a 'name' key, appending an incremental id, which outputs:

```
[
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "stuff"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "more stuff"
  }
]
```

How can I increment the START arg so that the second object has an id of 11 and so on?

EDIT: I should have posted the original json:

```
{
  "u": "stuff",
  "x": [1,2,3],
  "y": {
    "field": "value"
  },
  "z": {
    "stuffWithoutName": {
       "ex": "stuff"
    },
    "zz": {
       "name": "change me",
       "more": "stuff"
    },
    "randomKey":  {
       "name": "change me",
       "random": "more stuff"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `to_entries`, which, when given an array, will give the index for each item :

```
jq --arg START 10 '($START | tonumber) as $s
  | [.z[] | select(has("name"))]
  | to_entries
  | map({name:.value.name, id: ($s + .key) })'
```

This way, `id` goes from `10 + 0` to `10 + n`

Comment: Thank you very much! But can you see my edit? The .key is a string so I can't add it to the START value..

Comment: I don't think so, I'm getting this error: jq: error (at file.json:20): number (10) and string ("stuffWitho...) cannot be added.
Using just `jq --arg START 10 '.z | to_entries` shows that the .key is actually the key of the object (stuffWithoutName, zz and randomKey in this case).

Comment: From your answer, a ended up doing something like this:
`jq --arg START 10 '.z | to_entries | map(select(.value.name)) | to_entries | map({name: .value.value.name, id: (($START | tonumber) + .key)})'`
From the manual of jq, the key is the oject key (obviously in case of an object) and the array's index in case of an array. So I did `to_entries` again after checking if the object has the name key to get an array in which each key is an index.
Not the cleanest solution, but it works..
If you edit your solution I can accept it :)

Comment: FYI `--argjson` performs type coercion.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your jq has `foreach`:

```
# emit a stream of {id:_, value: _} objects
def counts(s; start):
  foreach s as $i (start-1; .+1; {id:., value: $i});

[ counts(.z[] | select(has("name")); $START|tonumber)
| {id, name: .value.name} ]
```

Since the above assumes you have `foreach`, you might as well also use the --argjson option, which allows you to pass the value of START in as a JSON number.

If your jq does not have `foreach`, then the above is easily modified to use `reduce` instead.

#### Postscript

Based on the revision to the question, it looks like you will want your jq program to have the form:

```
.z = [ ... ]
```

or

```
.z |= [[.[] | select(has("name"))] | to_entries | ...
```

or equivalent.